# Ajax GET request is null when successful

Tags: jquery, ajax, http, get

I'm fairly new to JS, and I've run into an issue when trying to send a GET request to my server via ajax call. The server is receiving the request and is executing the get properly, and the ajax call does succeed(executes succeed function), but the response is null. The GET works without issues when tested in Postman.

Ajax Call:

```
url = "http://localhost:8080/EmployeeLookup/SearchServlet?search=test"
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'GET',
    success: display,
    error: function(xhr,status,error){ alert(status); },
});
```

The request is being sent to the same server that this page is served, so there isn't any issue with Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

display function: Just testing if it is null for now. Testing with === also returns true.

```
function display(json) { 
    if(json == null) { 
        $("#text").replaceWith(json); 
    } else { 
        $("#text").replaceWith("Response was null. "); 
    }
}
```

The JSON that is sent back looks something like:

```
{
     "seachResult": "someresult" 
}
```

Comment: show us how you are handling the response.

Comment: Is it a cross origin request? Get requests do not require pre-flight requests but are still subject to Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: what is the filetype you are trying to pull? JSON? PHP? Also, please provide all code referenced (`url`, `display`, and the code you are trying to pull where applicable)

Comment: @Musa Then he wouldn't be getting to the success function.

Comment: you didn't define `body`, did you mean json? Also, when testing if somehthing is null, you should use `===` because `undefined == null` will be true, which is an entirely different problem.

Comment: Also you should check if the response is empty not null.

Comment: @DerekHenderson Sorry, body was left in. It was just changed.

Comment: Are you actually returning json, or are you returning text/html. Using json as a parameter name and returning html instead is very missleading, but it will still never be null. If anything, it'l be an empty string.

Comment: @Senor_Wilson I have updated my answer. Check it out.

Comment: @KevinB I used === and it still says it is null. The response is actual JSON, the response contentType is set as application/json.

Comment: Suggestion: take the exact JSON response and paste into jsonlint.com. If you're returning invalid JSON, it will become null.

Comment: @bfavaretto I've passed the response that I get while using Postman through the linter and it says it is valid JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always specify your dataType so that jQuery will consistently parse it properly.

```
// the http portion is not needed for same-domain requests
var url = "/EmployeeLookup/SearchServlet?search=test"
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: display,
    error: function(xhr,status,error){ alert(status); },
}); 

function display(json) {
    console.log(json);
}
```

Testing if data was returned is going to take more than testing if it is null, it will NEVER be null if you're using jQuery 1.9+ and the json dataType.

Comment: To suggest the proper way of testing for no data, we'll need to see an example of your data with results and without results.

Comment: I've tried to set dataType to json and the response is still null. Does ajax require something special in the header to get it to accept a response body?

Comment: No. What does your response look like?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't confusing null with undefined?

Comment: Also, you should never return "nothing" when the request is a JSON request. If anything, return an empty object, then you can test if the property exists on the object.

Comment: My response is just JSON(example posted above) or I send an error if there's an issue with the format of the parameters.

Comment: Then why are you testing for it to be null?

Comment: If that is indeed what you are returning, it wouldn't be null.

Comment: This is exactly why I'm confused. When the request is sent with Postman, or even just Chrome, the JSON is sent properly, but the ajax response doesn't reflect this. Is there anything else that would cause this other than my server just not sending anything or invalid json?

Comment: no. It should never be null. Have you opened the chrome console network tab to inspect the response headers/body?

Comment: Yes I have. The status code is 200 OK, and everything looks okay. The body is also valid JSON(Tested with linter). Is there anything in particular that I should be looking for in the headers?